# How to create a Matrix table in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I'm creating a Questionnaire app in which i need to display set of questions. One of my question type contains a grid, like the image below. Can anybody suggest an example or how to achieve this.

I want to create a table view like this
 [image: I want to create a table view like this]

My code is in Objective-C. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

There is no system control can perform the effect you want, you must customize one or use some open source code.

This is a sample for custom tableview to implement the effect you want, you can just take a look:

This is the ViewCtonroller.h:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface ViewController : UIViewController<UITableViewDelegate,UITableViewDataSource>

@property UITableView *tableView;

@end
```

This is the ViewController.m:

```
#import "ViewController.h"
#import "MyCell.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@property NSString *cellID;
@property int columns;
@property NSMutableArray *dataList;

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

_cellID = @"MyCell";
_columns = 2;
_dataList = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"data0",
@"data1",@"data2",@"data3",@"data4",@"data5",@"data6",@"data7",
@"data8",@"data9",@"data10",nil];

_tableView = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:[UIScreen mainScreen].bounds];
_tableView.separatorStyle = UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleNone;
_tableView.dataSource = self;
_tableView.delegate = self;
[self.view addSubview:_tableView];
}

-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section{
return (_dataList.count / _columns) + 1;
}

-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
MyCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:_cellID];
if (nil == cell) {
    cell = [[MyCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:_cellID];
}
if (0 == indexPath.row) {
    [cell SetData:@"Column0"and:@"Column1"];
}
else{
    [cell SetData:_dataList [(indexPath.row-1) * _columns]and:_dataList [(indexPath.row-1) * _columns + 1]];
}
return cell;
}

@end
```

This is MyCell.h:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface MyCell : UITableViewCell

-(void)SetData:(NSString*)str0 and:(NSString*)str1;

@end
```

This is MyCell.m:

```
#import "MyCell.h"

@interface MyCell()

@property UILabel *lb0;
@property UILabel *lb1;

@end

@implementation MyCell

- (void)awakeFromNib {
[super awakeFromNib];
// Initialization code
}

-(id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyle)style reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier{
self = [super initWithStyle:style reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];

_lb0 = [[UILabel alloc] init];
_lb0.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
[self addSubview:_lb0];

_lb1 = [[UILabel alloc] init];
_lb1.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
[self addSubview:_lb1];

return self;
}

-(void)SetData:(NSString*)str0 and:(NSString*)str1{
_lb0.text = str0;
_lb1.text = str1;
}

-(void)layoutSubviews{
_lb0.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.frame.size.width/2, self.frame.size.height);
_lb1.frame = CGRectMake(self.frame.size.width/2, 0, self.frame.size.width/2, self.frame.size.height);
}

@end
```

And you can also search some open source projects on GitHub.

Like this : [YHExcelView](https://github.com/ShenYahui/YHExcelView)

Hope it can help you.

Comment: can u suggest some examples

Comment: I have edit my answer, add a sample open source code for you, you can take a look and you can find the others on GitHub. @JestinSajiChacko

Answer (score 0):

You can use UICollectionView or UITableView to achieve this UI.

I would suggest you to use UICollectionView and you can configure how many views will be there in each row and customise each view as per your need.

In case of UITableViewCell, you need to design each row into a single UITableViewCell and load on the tableview data source, which seems to be complex in your case.

Comment: can u suggest some examples

Comment: https://www.appcoda.com/ios-programming-uicollectionview-tutorial/

Check out the UICollectionViewDataSource methods,

numberOfSectionsInCollectionView:

numberOfItemsInSection:

collectionView:cellForItemAtIndexPath:


These methods will be required to customise your UI.